# Converting a Mathematica code into Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, wolfram-mathematica

I am converting some codes from Mathematica into Python. Suppose I have the following list:

```
l = [["x1", "x2", "x3"], ["x4", "x5", "x6"], ["x7", "x8"], ["x9", 
"x10"], ["x11"]]
```

I want to turn above into a polynomial such that the length of each element in the list would be the power of the variable x. In Mathematica I do this by:

```
Total[x^Map[Length, l]]
```

which gives:

```
Output: x + 2 x^2 + 2 x^3
```

This means I have 1 element in list l with length 1, 2 elements with length 2 and 2 elements with length 3. In Python I have tried the following:

```
sum(x**map(len(l), l))
```

But this does not work as x is not defined, also I tried with "x", and it does not work either. I wonder how does one translate such code.

Comment: I have edited that, but ** does not fix the problem.

Comment: I would want to get the same output as mathematica, so I can do further analysis on the polynomial equation.

Comment: Let us make it super simplified, I have the list l which is just defined in python as the l i defined in this post. Namely it contains strings. Each elements of the list l has a specific length, there are two elements of length 3, two elements of length 2 and one element of length 1 (this is observable from l), question: how to makes a polynomial that counts the number of elements with respect to their length and sum them up, for instance 2 elements with length 3 would be written as 2x**3 and so on.

Comment: So, x is not defined, the polynomial is not evaluated, and the script literally prints `2x**3`?

Comment: exactly, problem is mathematica is made for symbolic calculations, while python is not. x is just a variable not defined.

Comment: You could create a string like this in pure Python, though I would not know, what this is good for. Maybe you are actually looking for [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: I have tried x = Symbol('x')
x^map(len(l), l) from Sympy yet I get SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '<map object at 0x110fecda0>'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: Either you try to explore SymPy and ask a separate question about your SymPy attempt, or you don't try to replicate exactly your Mathematica approach and use the libraries Python provides for your ultimate task. This whole question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Maybe you should provide more context, what the ultimate aim is, so people can suggest solutions that work in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a string according to your specifications, e.g., like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [["x1", "x2", "x3"], ["x7", "x8"], ["x9", "x10"], ["x4", "x5", "x6"], ["x11"]]

g = groupby(sorted(l, key = len), key = len)

s = " + ".join([" ".join([str(len(list(i))), "* x **", str(j)]) for j, i in g])
print(s)
#output
#1 * x ** 1 + 2 * x ** 2 + 2 * x ** 3
```

But this is just a string, while I assume from your question that you want to evaluate this formula later.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sympy](/questions/tagged/sympy) for this:

```
import sympy as sym

l = [["x1", "x2", "x3"], ["x4", "x5", "x6"], ["x7", "x8"], ["x9", "x10"], ["x11"]]

x = sym.Symbol('x')

expr = sym.S.Zero
for exponent in map(len, l):
    expr += x ** exponent

print(expr)
```

will give:

```
2*x**3 + 2*x**2 + x
```

---

Here I create a symbolic zero singleton [`sympy.S.Zero`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#zero) to which then I add the `x`'s raised to those powers that we can get from `map(len, l)`.

```
print(list(map(len, l)))
```

will give:

```
[3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is probably the SymPy solution the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution with sympy:

```
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.abc import x

l = [["x1", "x2", "x3"], ["x4", "x5", "x6"], ["x7", "x8"], ["x9", "x10"], ["x11"]]
powers = Matrix(list(map(len, l))) # Matrix([3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
raise_x_to_power = lambda y: x**y
output = sum(powers.applyfunc(raise_x_to_power))

print(output)
# 2*x**3 + 2*x**2 + x
```